# NoMethodError in Lines#show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

UPDATE: The answer bellow is correct. Just wanted to update what I did to solve the problem.
First I had to delete all my previous lines in the rails console.

Then I used the bye bug gem in my lines controller at the bottom of the create method to discover where the next bug occurred. I created a test line that I needed to delete again. so I ran

Line.last.delete in console.

This is the way my lines controller create method looks now (working no bugs)

```
def create
    if user_signed_in?
        @line = Line.create(line_params)
        if @line

        if params[:line][:previous_line_id].empty?
                @line.story = Story.create
                @line.save
            else
                @line.story = @line.previous_line.story
                @line.save
            end

            redirect_to line_path(@line)
        else
            flash[:error] = @line.errors
            redirect_to line_path(Line.find(params[:line][:previous_line_id]))
        end

    else
```

Finally I ran @Lines.each { |line| line.update.attribute(:story_id: 3)}

This gave the necessary association between lines and story.

ORIGINAL POST BELLOW.

I'm getting this error in my rails app. I  think that when I create a new line or start a story, it doesn't automatically add it to a story object. I've listed my show.html.erb file as well as my lines controller.rb file.

What am I missing? How do I get the controller to add data to the story object correctly?

Thanks!

[image]

I added a few lines of code to my lines controller:

```
class LinesController < ApplicationController

def new
    params[:previous_line_id].nil? ? @line = Line.new : @line = Line.find(params[:previous_line_id]).next_lines.create

    @lines = @line.collect_lines

    @ajax = true if params[:ajax]
    render :layout => false if params[:ajax]
    if @line.previous_line
        @line.update_attribute(:story_id, @line.previous_line.story.id)
    else
        story = Story.create
        @line.story = story
        @line.save
    end
end

def create
    if user_signed_in?
        @line = Line.create(line_params)
        if @line
            redirect_to line_path(@line)
        else
            flash[:error] = @line.errors
            redirect_to line_path(Line.find(params[:line][:previous_line_id]))
        end
    else

        flash[:error] = "Please sign in or register before creating a line!"
        unless params[:line][:previous_line_id].empty?
            redirect_to line_path(Line.find(params[:line][:previous_line_id]))
        else
            redirect_to root_path
        end
    end
end



# params[:id] should correspond to the first line of the story.
# if params[:deeper_line_id] is not nil, that means that they want to render up to the nested line id
def show
    @lines = Line.find(params[:id]).collect_lines
    @next_lines = @lines.last.next_lines.ranked
    @lines.last.update_attribute(:score, @lines.last.score + 1)
end

def select_next
    @line = Line.find(params[:id])
    @line.update_attribute(:score, @line.score + 1)
    @lines = [@line]

    @next_lines = @line.next_lines.ranked
    render :layout => false
end

def send_invite
    if user_signed_in?
        UserInvite.send_invite_email(current_user,Line.find(params[:id]), params[:email]).deliver
        flash[:notice] = "Your invite was sent!"
    else
        flash[:error] = "Please sign in"
    end
    redirect_to Line.find(params[:id])
end

private

def line_params
    params.require(:line).permit(:text, :previous_line_id, :user_id)
end

end
```

I added these lines to the controller pictured above

```
    if @line.previous_line
        @line.update_attribute(:story_id, @line.previous_line.story.id)
    else
        story = Story.create
        @line.story = story
        @line.save
    end
```

Here is my show.html.erb file

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-2">
</div>


<div class="box-container col-lg-7  ">


    <div id="story" class="box">
        <% @lines.each do |line| %>
            <span class="story-line" data-id="<%=line.id%>"><%= link_to line.text, '#', :class=>"story-line" %></span>
        <% end %>

    </div>

    <div id="next-steps">
        <%= render 'next_steps' %>
    </div>


<span style="font-size:.9em; margin-bottom:15px; display:block;">*If the links don't work, try refreshing.</span>

</div>

<div class="col-lg-2" style="padding-right:25px;">
    <%= render 'invite' %>
    Your Fellow Collaborators: <br />
    <div class="collaborators">
        <% @lines.last.story.collaborators.uniq.each do |collaborator| %>
            <%= link_to profile_path(:id => collaborator.id) do %>
                <%= image_tag collaborator.profile_image_uri, :class => "prof-icon" %>
            <% end %>
        <% end %>
    </div>
```

Story model

```
class Story < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :lines
has_and_belongs_to_many :collaborators, :class_name => "User", :join_table => "collaborators_stories", :association_foreign_key => :collaborator_id


def first_line

    self.lines.first_lines.first_lines.first
end
end
```

Here is my lines.rb file

class Line < ActiveRecord::Base

```
scope :first_lines, -> { where previous_line_id: nil}
scope :ranked, -> { order("score + depth DESC")}

belongs_to :user
belongs_to :story
belongs_to :previous_line, :class_name => "Line", :foreign_key => "previous_line_id"
has_many :next_lines, :class_name => "Line", :foreign_key => "previous_line_id"
validates_presence_of :text

after_create :update_depths


def update_depths
    line = self.previous_line
    while !line.nil?
        line.update_attribute(:depth, line.depth + 1)
        line = line.previous_line
    end
end

def first_line
    line = self
    while !line.previous_line.nil?
        line = line.previous_line
    end
    line
end

def collect_lines
    line = self
    lines = [self]
    while !line.previous_line.nil?
        lines.unshift(line.previous_line)
        line = line.previous_line
    end
    lines
end

end
```

Comment: It is hard to say without seeing your models. Check your `Line` model has `belongs_to :story` and `Story` has `has_many :collaborators`.

Comment: EDIT: I posted the story model to the bottom of my original post

Comment: Will you show the `collect_lines` method in `@lines = Line.find(params[:id]).collect_lines` in your show action please?

Comment: I just added the lines.rb file. Is that what you were looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is orphaned lines in your database. Look for them and associate it to a story, or delete it:

How to find orphaned records:
http://antonzolotov.com/2013/01/26/how-to-find-and-delete-orphaned-records-with-ruby-on-rails.html

Then review the create method to ensure a line should be part of a story:

```
#short example review activerecord relations

@story = Story.find(params[:story_id])
story.lines.create(line_params)
```

That should work.

EDIT:

```
def self.find_orphan_ids 
  Lines.where([ "user_id NOT IN (?) OR story_id NOT IN (?)", User.pluck("id"), Story.pluck("id") ]).destroy_all 
end
```

Comment: Do I need to add that to the story model or the lines model?

Comment: The fact is that this is just an example. The problem is that you are trying to access lines.last.story, and story is not setted for this lines.last. You will have to find out why you don't have a story, but you are still asking for collaborators.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'm new to coding in general so it will take me a while but I think I'll figure it out.

Comment: Do you need story to be set to all the lines? Or you can have lines without story?

Comment: Then the problem is in the database consistency, you are creating lines that doesn't belong to story. Search for them and delete it. Then review the create method.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, do I need to find the lines using my rails console? If so I think I can google around and figure out how to find the lines.

Comment: Thanks! I think this will solve my issue. I'll try it out and let you know.

Comment: For approach 3 in the guide linked above, where do I need to add the code, obviously I'll change subscription to line and channnles to story. what method/file should I use it in?

Comment: You can create a new method in the class: def self.find_orphan_ids; #method; end wich you can use as Lines.find_orphan_ids

Comment: ok so this is what I added to my lines.rb model 'def self.find_orphan_ids
  Lines.find_orphan_ids.where([
    "user_id NOT IN (?) OR story_id NOT IN (?)",
    User.pluck("id"),
    Story.pluck("id")
  ]).destroy_all 
 end' Still getting the same error.

Comment: Just Lines.where, without the .find_orphan_ids between.

Comment: I removed .find_orphan_ids and am still getting the same error. I know you are right about it being a database problem. What should I try next?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63963/discussion-between-jorge-de-los-santos-and-user3787971).